# Why function that use fs.stat doesn't return value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, fs

I have this sample on node version 4.2.1:

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

function getFilesizeInBytes(filename) {
    fs.stat(filename, (err, stats) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('inner: ' + stats.size);
        return stats.size;
    }); }

console.log('outer: '+ getFilesizeInBytes(__filename));
```

As result I have this output:

```
outer: undefined
inner: 325
```

Why outer is 'undefined'? How to fix it?

Comment: `fs.stat` is async, it hasn't returned anything by the time you do `console.log('outer: '+ getFilesizeInBytes(__filename));`

Comment: use the data `stats` in callback function, as its Async, it wont be available immediately and you cant predict when it can be available that is why callback functions are provided.

Comment: This is a very common question here and thus there are lots of prior answers that address the issue.  In a nutshell, your code is not executed line by line in order.  The callback for `fs.stat()` is asynchronous and thus is called someone LATER by the file system infrastructure, long after `getFilesizeInBytes()` has already returned.  So, returning a value from that callback just goes back into the file system infrastructure and not back to your function.